# Internal Server Error with Htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm creating a htaccess file, and trying to add a 404-page.
But if I go to a non existing page on this site, the 404-page doesn't show. Instead I get an "500-Internal Server Error".

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Htaccess:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^libwww-perl*" block_bad_bots
Deny from env=block_bad_bots

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^solution-([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /solutions.php?category=$1&solution=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^solution-([^/]*)$ /solutions.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page-([^/]*)$ /about.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: You can find the answer in your error log.

Comment: I can't find any log in my admin panel of the server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is the rule that is causing the error:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

This is because if the request is for a non-existing file *and* a non-existing  directory, then the rule gets applied. That means nothing will ever return a 404, because this rule will just get applied. Now the problem is that the rule rewrites a `.php` extension, even if a php file isn't actually there. So the rewrite engine loops again, and the rule gets applied again, and then the engine loops, rule gets applied again, etc.

You need to add another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

The condition says, if you add a `.php` to the end of the request, and if that file exists, then apply the rule.

Comment: Thanks! Worked great!

Answer (score 1):

You are close. In the future, you can debug your .htaccess file and figure out what's failing by adding `#` before each line (or group of lines) and seeing where the error is.

First, you don't need to redeclare `RewriteEngine On` twice. Once is enough.

If you disable the second block of rules (where the second `RewriteEngine On` is, you'll notice that your error handler works properly. That's where your error is coming from. So let's break it down.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

That means: for all requests that don't match a physical directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

That means: for all requests that don't match a physical file.

```
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

That means: for all matching conditions above, send a user to a filename suffixed by .php. Example: `mysite.com/bananas` would try to load the contents of the page `bananas.php`

So it's in that last line that's causing you errors. If you're intentionally typing in a non-existent URL, it's trying to load `bananas.php` and then throwing an error because that file doesn't exist. But the logic won't fail over to your ErrorDocument handler because it's already encountered an error looking for that file.

So the short solution is to remove that block of lines, and then anything not handled by the first block of lines will be served up by your /404.php. Or you can change that last line from `$1.php` to a catch-all script (e.g. `index.php`) that will then do it's own error checking and serve up the contents of your 404.php.